# python modules BeautifulSoup importError

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

My device is Kubuntu 14.04 desktop - VPS OVH. I am using Python 2.7.

I want to import `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

But, I have this error:

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I have installed `BeautifulSoup`. I have copied the module directly to my app folder and `BeautifulSoup` works. I want to run my app with out `BeautifulSoup` folder in my app folder.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying `BeautifulSoup` folder to your working directory, try to install it directly with this command:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: i was trying it but it not working. Python doesnt see all pip libs.

Comment: "ImportError: No module named bs4" -
but i have got installed this module.

Comment: Did you run `pip install beautifulsoup4`? What did you get when you run `pip freeze`?

Comment: Maybe your package is installed for another python interpreter that you have on your machine!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it directly then use

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Or you can store BeautifulSoup in a folder and then you can make it as a package by creating __init__.py file in that folder and all the subfolders that is contains, only then it will be treated as a package,in your case create __init__.py file inside a folder in current working directory and then put BeautifulSoup in it and try

```
from <folder_name> import BeautifulSoup
```